# Correct way of declaring a lambda inside a HashMap

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to declare a `HashMap` which will take a string and return a `Callable`.

I have:

```
Map<String, Callable<String>> commands = new HashMap<>();

commands.put("get", (String item) -> get(item));
```

where get is a function which returns void.

But I'm getting

```
"Bad return type in Lambda expression: Void cannot be converted into a string."
```

Why is it expecting the function to return a string? I want to pass the lambda a `String` and get `void` back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Callable<String>` has a method that returns a `String` (`V call() throws Exception`), so you can't use a lambda with void return type. You can use a `Consumer<String>` instead.

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> commands = new HashMap<>();

commands.put("get", (String item) -> get(item));
```

Comment: That won't compile.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks. And it's called with "accept" rather than "call", right? I'm learning Java but used to Python, so the functional paradigm is driving me up the wall.

Comment: @Mena That depends on how `get()` is defined, which wasn't specified in the question. If, for example, you have a `public static void get (String g) {}`, it does compile. I just tested it.

Comment: @bencollier Yes, the method of `Consumer` is `accept`.

Comment: @Eran I agree, my point was without the hidden context (having an accessible "get" method somewhere), that wouldn't compile. OP seems to agree with your solution though.

Comment: Well, it does compile. "get" is declared as a public void. Many thanks, saved me several hours of head-banging, I think.

Comment: @Mena Well, the OP wants the `get` method to be called by this lambda, which means we can assume it will be available.

Comment: @Eran yes, on second thought there is no way that `get` would come from any other place than some method out of the present picture, so yours is the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a putting a lambda representation of a `Callable<String>` as value into your map would be:

```
Map<String, Callable<String>> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put("get", () -> "some value");
```

That is because the functional interface `Callable<T>` has a single method returning a `T` value.